# How to run a script code in Linux Ubuntu when start up?

Tags: linux, shell-script, boot, sysvinit

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/deneme.sh
```

After that

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "HELLO WORLD"
```

then

```
chmod 755 deneme.sh
```

I didnt see Hello world text when I reboot to Linux Ubuntu ?

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is not executed just because it is present in that directory. It is executed because there is a link in another directory. I think in Ubuntu that directory is `/etc/rc.d/rc5.d`, but it might also be `/etc/init.d/rc5.d`. If you don't use run level 5, replace the 5 with the correct run level (3 or 2). If it is not there, run

```
find /etc -name 'S[0-9][0-9]*'
```

The files there are executed in the order given.

Comment: I have added my scrıpt from rc0 to rc5 but it dosent work.

Comment: And what exactly did you do? Add the output of `ls -l` to the question.